# Использование готовой C++ библиотеки из Java в Android

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake

Где-то на диске не в проекте Android Studio лежит готовая C++-библиотека в исходниках с готовым CMakeLists.txt. Эту библиотеку не хотелось бы трогать (копировать\перемещать в проект или изменять) и хотелось бы использовать этот готовый CMakeLists.txt.

Android Studio позволяет выбрать CMakeLists.txt и построить библиотеку без проблем. Но сама по себе эта библиотека в Android Java-проекте бесполезна, нужно сделать JNI-биндинг. А значит нужно написать второй CMakeLists.txt, который будет строить динамическую библиотеку, к которой нужно прилинковать первую библиотеку.

Вопрос, как всё это делается? Нужно ли разносить эти библиотеки по отдельным модулям? Или можно как-то вызвать сборку через CMake дважды из одного модуля и указать второму, что нужно использовать результаты первого? Какой путь передавать в target_link_libraries()?

А если делать отдельными модулями, то по идее статическая библиотека попадёт в aar архив и её не получится использовать из другого модуля?

Другими словами, как в Android Studio в связке Gradle + CMake одну нативную библиотеку прилинковать к другой, если обе библиотеки даны в исходниках и имеют свои независимые CMakeLists.txt?